# ParameterHandler for client side i.e. <jaxrs:client... providers

Tags: java, json, cxf

I need to convert LocalDate in client side received from REST Service in JSON form. I read about ParameterHandler, but looks like it works only for REST resource methods i.e. server side. Is there any thing to convert LocalDate on client side.

I tried implementing ParameterHandler and registered it in jaxrs:client providers. I can see constructor is called , but not the method fromString. Am I missing anything ? Below is my implementation:

```
public class JavaLocalDateParamHandler implements ParameterHandler<LocalDate>{

    public JavaLocalDateParamHandler() {
        System.out.println("defualt constr....");
    }
    @Override
    public LocalDate fromString(String s) {
        try{
        return LocalDate.parse(s);
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to parse param to java.time.LocalDate, param:" +s,e);
        }
    }
}
```

Client stub file:

```
 <jaxrs:client id="serviceClient"
                 serviceClass="pckge.RESTService"
                 username="abc"
                 password="paswswrd"
                 address="service URL">

    <jaxrs:features>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.transport.common.gzip.GZIPFeature"/>
            <cxf:logging/>
        </jaxrs:features>

        <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="pckg2.JavaLocalDateParamHandler" />
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider"/>
        </jaxrs:providers>

    </jaxrs:client>
```

Please note that I am able to fetch JSON string If I invoke resource directly from browser. SO only issue is my JavaLocalDateParamHandler fromString method is not called during conversion.

Does it work only on server side where REST resources(i.e. methods with diff annotations) are presented?

Comment: Please check if this answers your requirement as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168507/getcontext-method-of-customcontextresolver-is-not-called-by-jackson/38185004#38185004

Comment: Done thanks, Here is the solution.
http://www.coderanch.com/t/667353/tools/Java-LocalDate-Jackson-format#3114957